# validations with ClientSideValidations gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, client-side-validation

I am trying to validate my form with the gem ClientSideValidations, and works with presence true but I am trying to validate also with uniqueness but doesn't work until the form is sumited and just show the message once. I added the //= require rails.validations in aplicatios.js and installed the gem
this is my form:

```
   <%= form_for(@category, validate: true) do |f| %>
  <% if @category.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@category.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this category from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @category.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name  %>

  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :color %><br>
    <%= f.color_field :color %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and my model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :has_categories
    has_many :articles, through: :has_categories
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true 

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the original github doc:  *Wrapper objects and **remote** validations*
Which makes sense. I haven't used this before but IMO you can't just validate uniqueness on the client side alone, it needs to be done using AJAX to compare the data you're passing with that of the respective model at your backend. One of the way you can achieve this by setting `remote: true` in your form which will turn into an AJAX request.

**Update**- After struggling for a bit, I finally came across this issue [here](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations/issues/612). It states that uniqueness is disabled by default to prevent [Brute force attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack). Hence you need to implement this validation yourself using AJAX.
You may also look at [this](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations#wrapper-objects-and-remote-validations), if it makes any sense to you. I couldn't get it working either.

Comment: thanks for answer.  I have been watched this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_yasDxb8sk and all fine, but the uniqueness validations don't work for me. I don't know if I miss something

Comment: @LuisC I will need to see the full code of your form.

Comment: @LuisC I think it's important to write `validate: true` outside the `( )`, like this: `<%= form_for @user, validate: true do |f| %>`

Comment: still the same issue, I asked in the gem comments in github and they answer that: https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations-simple_form/issues/61 but its 
weird because I remove this line and still not working

Comment: Why don't you upload your project on bitbucket or github? I'd have to take a deeper look into it.

Comment: ok I uploaded my project thanks, this is the repo: https://github.com/luis77/blog2

Comment: the model and controller name is "Category"